# Panes and selected css option

Tags: java, javafx-2

I would like to know how can I change my `StackPane` css style when the `StackPane` is selected. Some components have the `:selected` or `:pressed` attribute in their css class style. Is it possible to add this extra attribute to `StackPane`, too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understood you, you want to introduce a custom [`PseudoClass`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/css/PseudoClass.html). This is possible with JavaFX 8.

For managing the state of your pseudo-class use an appropriate property binding / event listener to call [`Node.pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass, boolean)`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/Node.html#pseudoClassStateChanged-javafx.css.PseudoClass-boolean-).

Comment: i am just want to know what is wrong with my answer ?? i can give wrong answer ?? he ask something different ??

Comment: @AnshulParashar: In general, I think it's not a matter of right or wrong. On SO the questioner is free to accept that answer, which is most helpful for him. Personally, I like the way JavaFX makes it possible to separate the design from the application. This is followed more consistently by assigning CSS classes and pseudo-classes to your widgets and moving the corresponding design definitions into the css file.

Comment: thanks man to clarify it..i just asking for know something which is better and just check may be my answer was wrong. that's why asking..Its appreciable

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
StackPane stack = new StackPane();
    stack.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>
    () {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
            System.out.println("click on stack");
            stack.setStyle("-fx-background-color:pink");
        }
    });
```